# Need help please with working with forms and angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have found a tutorial on how to work with the angular js, but when I try to implement it into my work, I do not get the same results.
Here is the original:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/keren7/TcvxX/)

And here is my work:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/keren7/YZgam/5/)

Also, how can I get the values from the selected button with javascript (question, suggestion...)?

```
<div class="btn-toolbar">
                <div name="cate" class="btn-group" required="required">
                    <button class="btn" href="#"><i class="icon-coffee"></i> Question</button>
                    <button class="btn" href="#"><i class="icon-plus-sign-alt"></i> Suggestions</button>
                    <button class="btn" href="#"><i class="icon-stethoscope"></i> Product Support</button>
                </div>
                    <span class="label label-danger" data-ng-show="submitted && helpForm.cate.btn.$error.required">Required!</span>
```

Thank you!

Comment: make then `type=button"` so they don't submit and add an `ng-click`  that changes a scope variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @charlietfl said in the comments one way is to roll your own, the other is to use one of the libraries floating around like: http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/tooltips#buttons, which is by far the best option as they normally have fixed a lot of the possible bugs you may come across.

If you want to roll your own I have build a simplistic example here: http://codepen.io/SimeonC/pen/Lzjis

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" ng-click="toggle = 'question'" ng-class="{active: toggle == 'question'}" class="btn btn-default"><i class="icon-coffee"></i> Question</button>
  <button type="button" ng-click="toggle = 'suggestions'" ng-class="{active: toggle == 'suggestions'}" class="btn btn-default"><i class="icon-plus-sign-alt"></i> Suggestions</button>
  <button type="button" ng-click="toggle = 'support'" ng-class="{active: toggle == 'support'}" class="btn btn-default"><i class="icon-stethoscope"></i> Product Support</button>
</div>
```

**EDIT** In response to the comment, making this button 'required' is a matter of manual validation. Something like the following:

HTML:

```
<span class="label label-danger" ng-show="!toggle || toggle.length <= 0">Required!</span>
```

In the submit function of the form use:

```
if(!$scope.toggle || $scope.toggle.length <= 0) // prevent submission!
```

Comment: Thank you for that!
So, to address the value of the chosen button do I write $scope.toggle?

Comment: Yes, the basic rule for anything in angular.js is that a html reference to a variable has the `$scope.` taken off the front. (A very simplistic way of thinking about it).

Comment: Do I need to write $scope.button.toggle or just $scope.toggle?

Comment: Just $scope.toggle. If it helps you can think of ng-click="toggle = 'question'" (which also be a function) as the button telling the controller, "when I am clicked, run this on the current scope".

Comment: Hi Simeon, Thank you for your help! I can't seem to figure out how to make choosing the category as required. http://plnkr.co/edit/5LQauDjOL5ug8rQBCDUk?p=preview. Is it better to do it like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/M7b8qasBe3sshKGGYLxb?p=preview

Comment: I've edited the answer to give an example. Basically there is no ng-model for this, it's just changing a variable on the scope so you have to do the validation manually. If you want to use ng-model then use angular-strap. They have included a way of making radio/checkbox inputs look like buttons that should work with standard validation.

Comment: I have made the changes and it still doesn't work: http://plnkr.co/edit/5LQauDjOL5ug8rQBCDUk?p=preview

Comment: Do you want to try save it - it hasn't changed for me. (You might need to save and hit freeze as well).

Comment: Yup that one looks better. You were nearly there, I've updated it for you here: http://plnkr.co/edit/EwMo2RBVevCO0krcLWqE?p=preview